# Spastic cerebral palsy: Tools to help wearing pants

Tags: clothing

I have spastic cerebral palsy, I walk on walker or walking sticks, Botox and STR treatments are too expensive in my country, my family refuses to let me take relaxants and neural medians because I might get addicted or they might affect my brain or my productivity and work.

I can't reach my legs, they don't bend so well, and my back doesn't bend too, making it impossible for me to reach my legs.

Things I can't do mow:

- Wear and remove shoes and socks,I have ordered [this](https://bluecrate.com/products/sockzy), I think it will solve the problem
- Buckle and unbuckle jeans/pants buttons while standing using one hand, to solve this I'm planning to replace buttons with magnetic clasps
- I can't wear pants on my own

My brother saw me trying once again today, he told me to stop and that I have to understand what I can and cannot do, he told me that I have solve this problem using tools just like I have solved my other problems.

The thing is, I have not found any tool for that. What kind of tools can I use/create to wear my pants on my own. My only requirement is that the tool should be portable so that I can take it with me wherever I go.

Comment: Maybe a grasping foreceps like this one could help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G9t003J0Pk

Comment: @Herr_Schwabullek I'm going to buy one and give it a try, thank you!

Comment: Not an answer, but an observation: “You can’t do X” can be the greatest motivation... keeping my fingers crossed for you. Btw. and just to be sure I understand your question correctly: Do you mean “put on” instead of “wear” pants/socks?

Answer (score 4):

My difficulties are nothing like yours but my mind goes to think of answers.
Here we have varieties of shoe horns like you specified. One answer is something like that for pants made from what you can find.

Wearing suspenders on your pants would help getting them on without reaching down for them. Or just strings to your belt-loops. It would be worth it to leave a set on each pair of pants to simplify things.
Suspenders would simplify fastening your pants since they could stay up even when open.

You could adapt a walker to hold pants by the suspenders so you could step into or onto them. You could sit while you pulled the walker over you, pulling the pants up within reach.

For portability you would have to add loops, hooks or clamps to your regular walker that would help with pants. Stationary store Bull-dog clips are great for improvised fasteners. They come in many sizes. My desk and chairs are bristling with them.

Your Brother has not thought of the answer but that does not mean you can't. You will need to find your own way just as we all do. You may get discouraged but you don't have to stay discouraged. Let us know what you come up with. Others are also looking. 
Take care.

Comment: Welcome to the site Elliot, great answer. You give the tools to start thinking solutions, which is very valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Aboul the buttons - there is a company making custom shirts for people with cerebral palsy and they are using something like Velcro instead of buttons. So, apart from the magnets, using Velcro for your pants may be something to consider.

Comment: Velcro for pants, interesting